How to open list of hotkeys in obsiddian with keyboard?
There is a section that contains a list of hotkeys in the setting menu of Obsidian. How can we open the items of the setting menu like Core plugins, Appearance and etc just with a keyboard and no mouse? In particular, I want to set a hotkey for opening the list of all hotkeys available in obsidian, or at least the process of opening that with multiple keyboard shortcuts.

For opening the options in setting in Obsidian just by keyboard, I find a solution, but first we need to install some plugins. BRAT is an extension that creates a menu that contains all options of setting. As you can see in this picture:

When you install BRAT, an item will be added in the Ribbon menu, but there is no way to open that with the keyboard. So for the second step, we need to install obsidian-vimium. With this plugin, we are able to open any clickable items in the Ribbon menu by keyboard.
